# $\widetilde{H}_n(CX,X)\cong \widetilde{H}_n(SX) $

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to relate the homology of the suspension and the cone of a space by proving they are equal: $\widetilde{H}_n(CX,X)\cong \widetilde{H}_n(SX) $.

Here $ CX$ is the cylinder with all the base point identified: $CX= X\times I/{(x,s)\sim(x,y)\leftrightarrow s=t=1 } $. And $SX $ is the union of two cones identifying the bases. Equivalentley, $ SX$ is the cylinder of $ X$ with all the base points identified and all the ceiling points idenfitied: $SX=X\times I/{(x,s)\sim(x,y)\leftrightarrow s=t=1 \; \text{or}\; s=t=1} $

Comment: You can try to use the Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence, with two $CX$'s as open subsets (I'll let you guess how to do that) and something that looks like $X$ as an intersection.

Comment: You can also treat the suspension $SX$ as the quotient of $CX$ by the subspace $X\times 0$. In this case you get what you are looking for by comparing the exact sequences of the pairs $(CX,X)$ and $(SX,\ast)$.

Comment: If $X$ is a CW complex you can  note that $H_n(CX,X) \cong \tilde{H_n}(C(X)/X)=\tilde{H_n}(SX)$